# Playing audio in a loop with React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, rest, react-hooks

I'm using React.js and I have an API that returns audios:

```
{
   audios: [
      "https://thisisanaudiolink",
      "https://thisisanaudiolink",
      "https://thisisanaudiolink"
   ]
}
```

I don't want to use HTML's audio tag to play, but my custom button. How can I do that?

**What I've tried so far:**

I've tried this looping but all buttons play only the last audio:

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";

const Flashcards = () => {

const [audios, setAudios] = useState([
    "https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/carneiro/public/card_audios/d7f2a0-5c89ef/4.wav",
    "https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/carneiro/public/card_audios/d7f2a0-5c89ef/12.wav",
    "https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/carneiro/public/card_audios/d7f2a0-5c89ef/1.wav"
]);

const audioRef = useRef();

return (
    <div>
         {
             audios.map(audio => (
                <div key = {audio}>
                    <audio
                        controls = "controls"
                        preload = "auto"
                        autobuffer = "true"
                        style = {{display: "none"}}
                        ref = {audioRef}
                    >
                        <source src = {audio} />
                    </audio>


                    <button onClick = {() => audioRef.current.play()}>Play</button>
                </div>                  
             ))
         }
    </div>
   )
}
export default Flashcards;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that all button will play the last audio because you try to bind all the audio with one reference, each audio reference override each other until the last audio. There are several ways to achieve what you want. The easiest way would be create separate component to handle your audio play button. For example:

```
function AudioPlayer({ src }) {
  const audioRef = useRef();

  return (
    <div>
      <audio
        controls = "controls"
        preload = "auto"
        autobuffer = "true"
        style = {{display: "none"}}
        ref = {audioRef}
      >
       <source src={src} />
      </audio>

      <button onClick = {() => audioRef.current.play()}>Play</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Then you can use the AudioPlayer in your `audio.map`

```
audios.map(audio => <AudioPlayer src={audio} />);
```

Comment: This is the solution. Thanks a lot!